# Contour lines not showing up properly

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, data-visualization, matlab-figure, mixture-model

I am trying to visualize Gaussian mixture Model's contour lines to my scatter plots but they do not show up properly, first I thought they are getting overlapped by the points but the problem persists even if I draw the lines first and then plot the scatter points.

My code to generate the plots:

```
mn = min(pcaX); mx = max(pcaX);
for i = 1:6
    subplot(2,3,i);
    gscatter(pcaTest(:,1), pcaTest(:,2), testLabels);
    hold on;
    ezcontour(@(x,y)pdf(models{i},[x y]), [mn(1) mx(1) mn(2) mx(2)]);
    hold off, axis xy, title(['For class ',int2str(i),'components:',int2str(models{i}.NumComponents)]), xlabel('PC1'), ylabel('PC2');
end
```

That's how it looks: Notice the cut in contour lines

[image: current plot result]

Comment: Can you generate dummy data for a [minimum working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? I need `pcaTest`, `pcaX`, `testLabels`, and `models`.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to construct your problem even with `ezcontour`, but replacing it with [`fcontour`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fcontour.html) may do the job:

[image: fcontour]